# Format of axis labes in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to specify format of axis lables with Matplotlib?

Is it possible to add it in this command?

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x', scilimits=(0, 0), useLocale='True')
```

I would like to specify, that three numbers are before decimal comma and three after it, because label is not visible.

I tried something like

```
ytickformat('%.2f')
```

but I don't know how it use correctly.

[image]

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I would like to make axis label visible. I hope that setting format 3 number before decimal point and 3 after decimal point would help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Showing your tries and failure can help us better understand what you want, and we can help you better.

Comment: I editted my question

Comment: `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter("{x:3.3f}"))`

Comment: Thank you very much. Should I import something? It gives an error: `'StrMethodFormatter' is not defined`